# Angular 2: Resolve querylist?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

i currently create a angular 2 app, but i ran into problems with QueryList.

How do i manage to get values out of it?

I get the querylist with:

```
@ViewChildren('setSlider') setSliders: QueryList<Slides>;
```

This part works fine so far. Now i got this object:

```
QueryList {_dirty: false, _results: Array[4], _emitter: EventEmitter}
```

And now.. i just want to get the second result from it.

For Example: setSliders[0] ---> dont work.

Whats the best way to do that?

thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to do so. Check out API docs on Angular2 site: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/QueryList-class.html

The simplest way:

```
let secondSlide = this.setSliders.toArray()[2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this too.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.setSliders.toArray());
  this.setSliders.changes.subscribe(val => console.log(this.setSliders.toArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using the map method:

```
this.setSliders.map( slider => console.log(slider.nativeElement) );
```